# How to get value of dropdown instead of id yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

i am using a dropdown list and i wants to know is there any way i can get the value selected by user instead of `id`.

I am using `yii2` activeform with `ArrayHelper` map to populate the options which is like below

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'carname')->dropDownList(
            ArrayHelper::map(Cars::find()->all(), 'id', 'name'),
            ['prompt' => 'Select Car Name']
        ) ?>
```

In `controller` on form submit it returns `id` which is good but i want to save the `name` directly in the database.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'carname')->dropDownList(
            ArrayHelper::map(Cars::find()->all(), 'name', 'name'),
            ['prompt' => 'Select Car Name']
        ) ?>
```